# React Native, AwesomeProject, react-native run-ios : ** BUILD FAILED **

Tags: ios, react-native

I trying to run my first React Native... with AwesomeProject...
After a "react-native run-ios" i got :

> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following commands produced analyzer issues:  Analyze
>   RCTLocationObserver.m (1 command with analyzer issues)
>
> The following build commands failed:  CompileC
>   /Users/nicolasjoly/Devel/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTWebSocket.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTWebSocket.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTSRWebSocket.o
>   RCTSRWebSocket.m normal x86_64 objective-c
>   com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler   Analyze
>   RCTLocationObserver.m     CompileC
>   /Users/nicolasjoly/Devel/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTNetwork.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTNetwork.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTNetworkTask.o
>   RCTNetworkTask.m normal x86_64 objective-c
>   com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (3 failures) Installing
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject.app No
>   devices are booted. Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not
>   Exist
>   /Users/nicolasjoly/Devel/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/done.js:10
>         throw err;
>         ^
>
> Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c
>   Print:CFBundleIdentifier
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject.app/Info.plist
>   Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
>
> ```
> at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:464:13)
> at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:484:13)
> at _runIOS (/Users/nicolasjoly/Devel/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:82:34)
> at /Users/nicolasjoly/Devel/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:24:5
> at tryCallTwo (/Users/nicolasjoly/Devel/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
> at doResolve (/Users/nicolasjoly/Devel/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
> at new Promise (/Users/nicolasjoly/Devel/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3)
> at Array.runIOS (/Users/nicolasjoly/Devel/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:23:10)
> at Object.run (/Users/nicolasjoly/Devel/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cliEntry.js:88:13)
> at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:88:7)
> ```

Thank you for your help !!

Comment: Do you have the last version of xcode installed?

Answer (score 7):

Try running `react-native upgrade`and then say yes to all subscribing messages. After that, try `react-native run-ios` again

Answer (score 0):

First, run the command `react-native upgrade`. Then, delete your `ios` and `android` folders. Then, run `react-native eject`. Then, run `react-native-git-upgrade`. Then, run `react-native link`.

Finally, run the `react-native run-ios` command again.