# Facebook SDK causes React Native build to fail

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

My team is building our first iOS app using React Native. For some reason on my Mac only, the build fails after running `react-native run-ios`. This has been happening since we added Facebook authentication with the `react-native-fbsdk`.

We are all running node -v 7.0 and the latest version of Xcode. I have even tried deleting the repo locally and cloning it back down. As an experiment, another member of my team deleted his repo locally, cloned it back down, and was able to get everything working. We sat next to each other and did the exact same steps and it worked for him but not me.

Below is the error message I receive in my terminal:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/philmok/js_projects/pLot/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTFBSDK.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTFBSDK.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTFBSDKGraphRequestManager.o RCTFBSDK/core/RCTFBSDKGraphRequestManager.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/pLot.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/pLot.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

Per the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38028137/react-native-awesomeproject-react-native-run-ios-build-failed), I have tried running `react-native upgrade`. This will allow the build to complete but it prevents Facebook authentication from working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have downloaded the FBSDK for fb login. Place it in your documents folder and then open your project in xcode. click your project in the left menu and select the build settings tab, give 'framework path' the path to your FBSDK in documents.

Comment: What are you supposed to do in android for that?

Comment: @ShariqMusharaf Not sure, this was iOS specific. I have not tried it for Android

Answer (score 2):

add

```
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

to your `Podfile` and then `pod install`

Answer (score 1):

Did you went through all configuration steps? Here is great introduction, step by step how to add facebook sdk to react native app: https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login . Btw. I recommend to use this lib if you can, I had many problems with official facebook sdk, moved to that one, and everything works.

Comment: The members of my team are already using the official React Native fbsdk and it works for all of them. Switching to another lib is not an option

Comment: And did you try to run app from `xCode`? Sometimes you have to set `BundleIdentifier` manually (`xCode` -> `General` -> `Bundle Indentifier` to something like `com.myproject`)

Comment: Yes, the bundle identifier has been set